# What does a # before a type name mean in F#?

Tags: f#

What does a `#` before a type name mean in F#?

For example [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/d6244d4a1b7bc4efce42bc050ad08384cdce0320/tests/fsharp/core/forexpression/test.fsx#L23):

```ml
let getTestData (inner : int [] -> #seq<int>) (outer : #seq<int> [] -> #seq<'U>) =
    (testData |> Array.map inner) |> outer
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The syntax `#type` is called a "flexible type" and it is a shortcut for saying that the type can be any type that implements the given interface. This is useful in cases where the user of a function may want to specify a concrete type (like an array or a list).

For a very simple example, let's look at this:

```
let printAll (f: unit -> seq<int>) = 
  for v in f () do printfn "%d" v
```

The caller has to call `printAll` with a lambda that returns a sequence:

```
printAll (fun () -> [1; 2; 3]) // Type error
printAll (fun () -> [1; 2; 3] :> seq<int>) // Works, but tedious to write!
```

If you use flexible type, the return type of the function can be any implementation of `seq<int>`:

```
let printAll (f: unit -> #seq<int>) = 
  for v in f () do printfn "%d" v

printAll (fun () -> [1; 2; 3]) // No problem!
```

In reality, the syntax `#typ` is just a shortcut for saying `'T when 'T :> typ`, so you can rewrite the function in my example as:

```
let printAll<'T when 'T :> seq<int>> (f: unit -> 'T) = 
  for v in f () do printfn "%d" v
```